# JHipster: run production profile on localhost

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I am new to JHipster and I found it is easy to generate a application without sweat. I tried to generate a simple monolithic application and ran on dev mode and it worked like charm. However, when I want to run production mode using "./mvnw -Pprod" it shows error:

```
 2022-06-30 14:52:30.639 ERROR 9088 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:148)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:160)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:613)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at com.sample.JtestingApp.main(JtestingApp.java:69)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/Jtesting/prod/main": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:255)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:109)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-30T14:52:30+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:run (default-cli) on project jtesting: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These are my choices when I generating application in case you need it:
[image]

I didn't edit or change any coding so far because I want to see the difference of dev and prod. And I did searched on other posts but still not success to run on prod mode..
Any form of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose to use JHipster registry to serve configuration and to scale up, so when you run your app in production mode you must start jhipster-registry application and also make sure you have copied the application properties to the registry repository (either git or a directory).

Same thing for all dependencies on external systems like your MySQL database.

Easiest way to start them in local development environment is to use docker-compose, see official doc for details: https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/

If you want only to build your app (not running it) using `prod` profile, you can do it without external systems, you just need to specify the `package` goal: `mvnw -Pprod package`

Comment: Hi, i refered to the link and it works, but I still got a question. By this sentence "You chose to use JHipster registry to serve configuration and to scale up", does that mean if I don't choose JHipster registry I don't need to docker up Registry?

Comment: Yes absolutely, for most monolith projects, using the registry is just overkill, this is why it's not the default choice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I just post here for other begineers or my future reference (only run for localhost, not cloud). Running `dev` mode is easy, just use `mvnw` after generating application. However, for `prod` mode, there are 2 ways to start:

**First way (when you choose to use JHipster Registry):**

1. after generating application, `./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild` or `./mvnw -Pprod package verify jib:dockerBuild --offline`
2. run another console/terminal, `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up`, it will run all required services (database, JHipster Registry ,etc)
3. run `./mvnw -Pprod` , the application should be running successfully.

**Second way (not choosing JHipster Registry):**

1. just run `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up`  instead of `./mvnw -Pprod`, it will automatically run the application successfully.

*NOTE: the **mysql** inside `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up` can be changed depends on your chosen database.

Also, I did not connect to any external database.